# How can I send a list of supported intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a simple application that can be controlled by a service. In order to control this application, the service must know the commands that can send to it, so I thought it should be the application to provide a list of these commands, as follows:

1. The application may have a secondary activity that responds to the `MY_ACTION_GET_COMMANDS` intent (so I should define an intent-filter in the *"AndroidManifest.xml"* file).
2. The service knows that he can send this type of intent using the `startActivityForResult` method.
3. When the application receives this type of intent, the appropriate activity responds to the sender by sending a list of supported commands (ie, a list of intent).

How can I send a list of supported intents?

**UPDATE:** note that the application and the service are in different packages.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand why u need to display an activity of these intents. Is this something that a real user will see?

If you really want to get list of all intents a particular app is listening to you can use PackageManager. Retrieve [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) using [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Then you will be able to scan through all defined receivers in that app.

I may be able to help more if you explain a bit further.

Comment: _I am not sure I understand why u need to display an activity of these intents. Is this something that a real user will see?_ The user of the service should be able to associate a command (a simple string, for example, "write", "save to file") to each of intents that are supported by the application. The application is separated from the service (they are part of different package). The service includes a speech recognizer, then the user can issue a command to control the application.

Comment: Well, then it's either fetching them using PackageManager (you can do it even from service app) or just returning a pretty list (with human readable descriptions) from remote app. You can either do it using activity or query raw data using content provider (which is quite heavyweight IMO, but may be useful if you also want to write state changes)...

Comment: `PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("org.example", PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
for (ActivityInfo ai : pi.receivers) {
    // Where are the intent filters?
}`

Comment: Well, yeah, sorta... Google have great documentation on these methods, so this should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the supported intents as list from the child activity back to the parent.

```
 Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("com.customintent.INTENT_ONE");
        a.add("com.customintent.INTENT_TWO");
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list",a);

        this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```